# Is deploying of custom metadata records from sandbox going to overwrite existing metadata records in production

Tags: apex, sandbox, production, custom-metadata

I wonder about this. Let's say:

**Step 1:** I deploy custom metadata from Sandbox to Production.

**Step 2:** Then somebody adds records to the deployed metadata in Production. This will create a difference in the records between Production and Sandbox.

**Step 3:** Now let's say I make some changes to the records in the Sandbox and deploy them to Production again. Is this going to overwrite the different records that were added in **Step 2**?

If so is there a way to preserve these records?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the records have different names, there will be no overwriting. If the records have the same names, they'll be overwritten,  just as if you'd created,  say, custom fields with the same name in sandbox and production.

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't find anybody to answer this question.